# Get Latitude/Longitude Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I'm learning python and am currently trying to parse out the longitude and latitude from a "Location" column and assign them to the 'lat' and 'lon' columns. I currently have the following code:

```
def getlatlong(cell):
    dd['lat'] = cell.split('\n')[2].split(',')[0][1:]
    dd['lon'] = cell.split('\n')[2].split(',')[1][1:-1]

dd['Location'] = dd['Location'].apply(getlatlong)

dd.head()
```

The splitting portion of the code works. The problem is that this code copies the lat and lon from the last cell in the dataframe to all of the 'lat' and 'lon' rows. I want it to split the current row it is iterating through, assign the 'lat' and 'lon' values for that row, and then do the same on every subsequent row.

I get that assigning dd['lat'] to the split value assigns it to the whole column, but I don't know how to assign to just the row currently being iterated over.

Data sample upon request:

```
Index,Location
0,"1554 FIRST ST\nLIVERMORE, CA 94550\n(37.67930642, -121.7765857)"
1,"1554 FIRST ST\nLIVERMORE, CA 94550\n(37.67931141, -121.7765988)"
2,"138 14TH ST\nOAKLAND, CA 94612\n(37.80140803, -122.26369831)"
3,"4014 MACARTHUR BLVD\nOAKLAND, CA 94619\n(37.78968061, -122.19690846)"
4,"4014 MACARTHUR BLVD\nOAKLAND, CA 94619\n(37.78968557, -122.19692165)"
```

Comment: Can you show an example of your data?

Comment: A given row value looks like this "1554 FIRST ST\nLIVERMORE, CA 94550\n(37.67930642, -121.7765857)"

Comment: Explanation for downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see my approach below. It is based on creating a DataFrame with `lat` and `lon` columns and then adding it to the existing dataframe.

```
def getlatlong(x):
    return pd.Series([x.split('\n')[2].split(',')[0][1:], 
                      x.split('\n')[2].split(',')[1][1:-1]],
                      index = ["lat", "lon"])

df = pd.concat((df, df.Location.apply(getlatlong)), axis=1)
```

Comment: This gave me `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: That did it! Thank you Abhishek!

Comment: Great answer, but there are two typos. getlatlong should read: def getlatlong(x):
    return pd.Series([x.split('\n')[2].split(',')[0][1:], 
                      x.split('\n')[2].split(',')[1][1:-1]],
                      index = ["lat", "lon"])

Answer (score 1):

This addresses another technique you can use to get the answer, but isn't exact code you need. If you add sample data i can tailor it.

Using Pandas's build in str methods you can save yourself some headache as follows:

```
temp_df = df['Location'].str.split('\n').str.split().apply(pd.Series)
```

The above splits the Location column on spaces, and then turns the split values into columns. You can then assign just the Latitude and Longitude columns to the original df.

```
df[['Latitude', 'Longitude']] = temp_df[[<selection1>, <selection2>]]
```

str.split() also has an expand parameter so that you can write .str.split("char", expand=True) to spread out the columns without the apply.

## Update

Given your example, this works for your specific case:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Location": ["1554 FIRST ST\nLIVERMORE, CA 94550\n(37.67930642, -121.7765857)"]})
df[["Latitude", "Longitude"]] = (df['Location']
                                 .str.split('\n')
                                 .apply(pd.Series)[2]  # Column 2 has the str (lat, long)
                                 .str[1:-1]  # Strip the ()
                                 .str.split(",", expand=True)  # Expand latitude and longitude into two columns
                                 .astype(float))  # Make sure latitude and longitude are floats

Out:
    Location                                            Latitude    Longitude
0   1554 FIRST ST\nLIVERMORE, CA 94550\n(37.679306...   37.679306   -121.776586
```

## Update #2

@Abhishek Mishra's answer is faster (takes only 55% of the time, since it goes through the data fewer times). Worth noting that the output from that example has strings in each column, so you might want to modify to get values back to floats.

Comment: When I tried doing this every temp_df row comes out as NaN

Comment: Can you add a data sample, so I can play around? Hard to diagnose otherwise.

Comment: Just added to original post

Answer (score 0):

```
for ind, row in dd.iterrows():
    dd['lat'].loc[ind] = dd['Location'].loc[ind].split(',')[0][1:]
    dd['lon'].loc[ind] = dd['Location'].loc[ind].split(',')[1][1:-1]
```

PS: iterrows() is slow.